# Context free grammar for L{a^n b^m c^t where t>0,m>0,n>2}

Tags: context-free-grammar

For a context free grammar for `L{a^n b^m c^t where t>0,m>0,n>2}`

```
S -> ABC
A ->aB|a
B ->bB|b
C ->cC|c
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. Your current grammar would allow the solution `abc` which is not part of your grammar since `a` does not appear more than two times.

It can be constructed the following way:
`S -> ABC -> aBC -> abC -> abc`

I would suggest the following grammar:

`S -> aaABC`
`A -> aA|a`
`B -> bB|b`
`C -> cC|c`